# laravel-excel 3.1 with laravel framework 6.2 and php 7.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, laravel-6.2

I have problem with laravel-excel 3.1 after i have been upgrade laravel version and php version i got some requirement from laravel to upgrade laravel-excel too. after that i got problem with excel-export not support new version(3.1) before i use 2.1. anyone can help to update my currently code above? pls! and Thanks Guys!

```
private function export_customer_invoice_report($customer_invs)
    {
        $data_array = array([
            'Issue Date',
            'Purchase Order Invoice',
            'Bag ID',
            'SKU',
            'Color-Size',
            'QTY',
            'Sale Price',
            'Additional Discount',
            'Actual Sale Price',
            'Delivery Fee',
            'Customer Balance',
            'Pre-Paid Amount',
            'Supplier Actual Price',
            'Remark']);

        foreach ($customer_invs as $key => $value) {
            $product_variants = Helper::get_pro_option_id($value->order_item_id);
            $doubleSpace = strip_tags($product_variants);
            $singleSpace_product_variants = str_replace("\n ", "", $doubleSpace);
            $issue_date = Helper::dateTimeDisplay($value->created_at);
            $additional_dis = $value->additional_discount_percent ? $value->additional_discount_percent : 0;
            $sale_price_after_disc = ($value->unit_price * $value->count_item) - ((($value->unit_price * $value->count_item) * $value->discount_percent) / 100);
            $total_sale_price_discount_addit = ($sale_price_after_disc * $value->additional_discount_percent) / 100;
            $actual_sale_price = $sale_price_after_disc - $total_sale_price_discount_addit;

            // check if supplier actual price is zero, take from supplier price instead
            $supplier_actual_price = $value->supplier_order_actual_price > 0
            ? $value->supplier_order_actual_price
            : $value->supplier_price;
            $data_list = array(
                $issue_date,
                $value->invoice_id,
                $value->bag_id,
                OrderItem::getProductSKU($value->order_item_id),
                $singleSpace_product_variants,
                $value->count_item,
                '$' . number_format($sale_price_after_disc, 2),
                '%' . $additional_dis,
                '$' . number_format($actual_sale_price, 2),
                '$' . number_format($value->delivery_price, 2),
                '$' . number_format($value->customer_balance, 2),
                '$' . number_format($value->prepaid_amount, 2),
                '¥' . number_format($supplier_actual_price, 2),
                $value->note,
            );
            array_push($data_array, $data_list);
        }

        Excel::create('customer_invoice_report', function ($excel) use ($data_array) {
            // Set the title
            $excel->setTitle('no title');
            $excel->setCreator('no no creator')->setCompany('no company');
            $excel->setDescription('report file');
            $excel->sheet('sheet1', function ($sheet) use ($data_array) {
                $sheet->cells('A1:M1', function ($cells) {
                    $cells->setBackground('#e7e7e7');
                    $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
                });
                $row = 1;
                $startRow = -1;
                $previousKey = '';

                foreach ($data_array as $index => $value) {
                    if ($startRow == -1) {
                        $startRow = $row;
                        $previousKey = $value[2];
                    }
                    $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, $value[0]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $row, $value[1]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $row, $value[2]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('D' . $row, $value[3]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('E' . $row, $value[4]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('F' . $row, $value[5]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('G' . $row, $value[6]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('H' . $row, $value[7]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('I' . $row, $value[8]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('J' . $row, $value[9]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $row, $value[10]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('L' . $row, $value[11]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('M' . $row, $value[12]);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('N' . $row, $value[13]);
                    $nextKey = isset($data_array[$index + 1]) ? $data_array[$index + 1][2] : null;

                    if ($row >= $startRow && (($previousKey != $nextKey) || ($nextKey == null))) {
                        $cellToMergeJ = 'J' . $startRow . ':J' . $row;
                        $cellToMergeK = 'K' . $startRow . ':K' . $row;
                        $cellToMergeL = 'L' . $startRow . ':L' . $row;
                        $sheet->mergeCells($cellToMergeJ);
                        $sheet->mergeCells($cellToMergeK);
                        $sheet->mergeCells($cellToMergeL);
                        $sheet->cells('J' . $startRow . ':J' . $row, function ($cellsJ) {$cellsJ->setValignment('center');});
                        $sheet->cells('K' . $startRow . ':K' . $row, function ($cellsK) {$cellsK->setValignment('center');});
                        $sheet->cells('L' . $startRow . ':L' . $row, function ($cellsL) {$cellsL->setValignment('center');});
                        $startRow = -1;
                    }
                    $row++;
                }
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
    }
```

Comment: "i got problem" is not much to go on. And why not update to a current version of Laravel instead of one that's a couple of years old?

Comment: @miken32 Laravel 6.x is the latest LTS release (released Sept 2019). Some orgs may prefer to stick to LTS releases so they don't have to upgrade their frameworks every 6 months. That's a decision that depends on the needs and resources of the org. LTS vs latest is a debate that's beyond the scope of this question, however, since the OP would have the exact same problem if they upgraded to Laravel 8. :)

Answer (score 0):

We just did this for a project. The laravel-excel package is very different when moving from 2.x to 3.x. The paradigm shifted from simply being a utility to representing imports and exports as self-contained classes. I would recommend moving all of your logic for generating the the export out of your controller and into this class, but you can keep it in your controller if you prefer. Here's the general idea of what you need to do:

First, create an export class:

```bash
php artisan make:export CustomerInvoiceReport
```

Then, edit the newly created class, which should be in `app/Exports/CustomerInvoiceReport.php`. If `$customer_invs` is an array, implement the `FromArray` interface. If it's a Laravel Collection, implement the `FromCollection` interface. Also, you can use the `Exportable` trait to add the `download()` method to the class (which we'll use later).

For this example, I'll assume it's an array. You need to modify the `array()` method so that it returns your modified array (I'll leave that to you):

```php
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Invoice;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;

class CustomerInvoiceExport implements FromArray
{
    use Exportable;

    protected $invoices;

    public function __construct(array $invoices)
    {
        $this->invoices = $invoices;
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        // insert/move your logic for modifying the array here

        return $this->invoices;
    }
}
```

Finally, in your controller, simply instantiate your export class and return a download:

```
use App\Exports\CustomerInvoiceReport;

...

private function export_customer_invoice_report($customer_invs)
{
    return (new CustomerInvoiceReport($customer_invs))
        ->download('customer_invoice_report.xlsx');
}
```

There are other things you can control in the export class, such as column [headers](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html#adding-a-heading-row) and [formatting](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html). Refer to the [documentation on creating exports](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/) for more information.

Comment: how to merge cell like my currently condition? thanks you @wunch